# Delete record from database using ajax and jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hi i have a product_detail.php page. In this page description about product and edit and delete button. I am trying to delete product on click delete button. I getting alert message **Are you sure you want to delete this product?** but nothing work. Here is my product_detail.php page code below:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <h4><strong>Description:</strong></h4><hr>
    <p class="text-justify"><?php echo $row['description'];?></p>

    <form id="product_detail">
        <button class="btn product_publish" type="button">Publish Live</button>
        <button class="btn btn-edit" name="btn-edit">Edit</button>
        <button class="btn product_delete" type="button" id='del_<?php echo $id; ?>'>Delete</button>
    </form>                                                 
</div>
```

Here is my validation.js page code:

```
$('.product_delete').click(function(){
var el = this;
var id = this.id;
var splitid = id.split("_");
// Delete id
var deleteid = splitid[1];

if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this product?")){          
    $.ajax({
    url:'includes/backend_product_detail.php',
    type: "POST",
    data: { id:deleteid },      
    success:function(answer_from_actionpage){
    if(answer_from_actionpage == 1){
        window.location.href="product.php";
        //$('.form-control').val("");
    }else{
        $('.error').html(answer_from_actionpage);
    }
}
})
}
});
```

and here is my backend_product_detail.php page code:

```
<?php   
    include("dbconfig.php");

    $id=$_POST['id'];       
        $sql="DELETE FROM product WHERE id='$id'";
        if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
            echo 1;
        }       
?>
```

What can i do for delete particular product record.

Comment: is there any error in your browser console.

Comment: No, any error. Getting alert message Are you sure you want to delete this product? but not working.

Comment: Please check error in console, by pressing `ctrl + shift + i` ?

Comment: @Ketaki check here      var deleteid = splitid[1]; is coming.

Comment: @Mohit Kumar where to check  var deleteid = splitid[1]; is coming. I am beginner in PHP.

Comment: in validation.js after var deleteid = splitid[1];   write console.log(deleteid );   and see in console you are geting id or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this in your jquery code:

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "includes/backend_product_detail.php",
  data: { id: deleteid }
})
  .done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
  });
```

And also make sure to prevent from [SQL Injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) in your php script and first check your `$id` with following if-statement:

```
// ...
if (is_numeric($id)){
    $sql="DELETE FROM product WHERE id=" . $id;
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
        echo 1;
    }   
}
```